# cant's save a keras/tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to save a model having two models inside.

```
class DualEncoder(keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, text_encoder, image_encoder, temperature=1.0, **kwargs):
    super(DualEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.text_encoder = text_encoder
    self.image_encoder = image_encoder
    self.temperature = temperature
    self.loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")
```

Full Code.

```
class DualEncoder(keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, text_encoder, image_encoder, temperature=1.0, **kwargs):
    super(DualEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.text_encoder = text_encoder
    self.image_encoder = image_encoder
    self.temperature = temperature
    self.loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")

@property
def metrics(self):
    return [self.loss_tracker]

def call(self, features, training=False):
    # Place each encoder on a separate GPU (if available).
    # TF will fallback on available devices if there are fewer than 2 GPUs.
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        # Get the embeddings for the captions.
        caption_embeddings = text_encoder(features["caption"], training=training)
    with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
        # Get the embeddings for the images.
        image_embeddings = vision_encoder(features["image"], training=training)
    return caption_embeddings, image_embeddings

def compute_loss(self, caption_embeddings, image_embeddings):
    logg = tf.constant([[0, 0], [62, 61], [0, 0]])
    image_em = tf.pad(image_embeddings, logg, mode ='CONSTANT', constant_values=0)
    print("image em is", image_em.shape)
    logits = (
        tf.matmul(caption_embeddings, image_em, transpose_b=True)
        / self.temperature
    )
    print("logits shape is", logits.shape)
    
    images_similarity = tf.matmul(
        image_em, image_em, transpose_b=True
    
    )
    print("images similarity shape is ", images_similarity.shape)
    captions_similarity = tf.matmul(
        caption_embeddings, caption_embeddings, transpose_b=True
    )

    print("captions similarity shape is", captions_similarity.shape)
    targets = keras.activations.softmax(
        (captions_similarity + images_similarity) / (2 * self.temperature)
    )
    print("targets shape is ", targets.shape)
    # Compute the loss for the captions using crossentropy
    captions_loss = keras.losses.kl_divergence(
        y_true=targets, y_pred=logits, #from_logits=True
    )
    print("caption loss is", captions_loss.shape)
    # Compute the loss for the images using crossentropy
    images_loss = keras.losses.kl_divergence(
        y_true=tf.transpose(targets), y_pred=tf.transpose(logits),
    )
    # Return the mean of the loss over the batch.
    print("image loss is", images_loss.shape)
    #return (captions_loss + images_loss) / 2
    return tf.matmul( captions_loss, images_loss) / 2
    #(tf.reduce_sum(captions_loss, axis=0) + images_loss) / 2
    #return (captions_loss[0, :] + images_loss + captions_loss[1, :]) / 2

def train_step(self, features):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Forward pass
        caption_embeddings, image_embeddings = self(features, training=True)
        loss = self.compute_loss(caption_embeddings, image_embeddings)
    # Backward pass
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))
    # Monitor loss
    self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
    return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result()}

def test_step(self, features):
    caption_embeddings, image_embeddings = self(features, training=False)
    loss = self.compute_loss(caption_embeddings, image_embeddings)
    self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
    return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result()}
```

When I save the dual encoder then I get this error. `NotImplementedError: Saving the model to HDF5 format requires the model to be a Functional model or a Sequential model. It does not work for subclassed models, because such models are defined via the body of a Python method, which isn't safely serializable. Consider saving to the Tensorflow SavedModel format (by setting save_format="tf") or using` save_weights`.

However I can save `text_encoder` and `image_encoder`.

Can I load these models like below will it work?

```
class DualEncoder(keras.Model):
   def __init__(self, text_encoder, image_encoder, temperature=1.0, **kwargs):
     super(DualEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     self.text_encoder = new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('text_encoder')
     self.image_encoder = new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('image_encoder')
     self.temperature = temperature
     self.loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")
```

Comment: It is saying that your model should be "Functional" or "Sequential" Meaning that you have just assigned the variables in the class but you have not used it anywhere, then try to make this model in a sequential way, rather than a subclass Model.

Comment: I have shared the full code, can you help to make this model sequential?

Comment: Now, it seems better, I will give you the instruction that how you will do this, first of all, your models, text-encoder, and image-encoder should also be implemented using Keras functional API's and then and finally separate the loss function from Model() class, other than then update the gradients then use this code which I am sharing.